# mySQL > Limit the same amount of value returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am developing Content / Comment system.. 
I want: For each content in array to be returned maximum 10 comments..
I tryed `LIMIT 20`, but this is limiting the total results, how to limit only the repeated values in column `comment_id`

`$contentidArray` is array of content ID's

```
$sthandler = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content_id in (".$contentidArray.") order by total_reactions desc");

$sthandler->execute();
```

Comment: So you want to add a `LIMIT 10`?

Comment: What is the problem are u facing?

Answer (score 0):

Check this query for self join to fetch max 10 records per content_id,

```
select c.* FROM comments c
left join comments c1 ON c.content_id = c1.content_id AND c.id <= c1.id
group by c.id
having COUNT(*) <= 10
order by c.content_id, c.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it now..